# How to bind list to the view without a middle model class?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I have this code that works just fine.

It retrieves data from the repository, sets it to listPlaces and binds listPlaces to the view.

Controller

```
ListPlaces listPlaces = new ListPlaces();
listPlaces.setListPlaces(placeRepository.selectPlaces(idUser));

ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView("/myplaces.html");
modelAndView.addObject("listPlacesBind", listPlaces);
```

Model

```
public class ListPlaces {
    
    private List<Place> listPlaces;

    public List<Place> getListPlaces() {
        return listPlaces;
    }

    public void setListPlaces(List<Place> listPlaces) {
        this.listPlaces = listPlaces;
    }
    
}
```

View

```
<th:block th:each="place, itemStat : *{listPlaces}">                    
<span th:text="*{listPlaces[__${itemStat.index}__].codPlace}" />
```

Then came to mind I could simplify this code by doing the following:

1. Removed ListPlaces model class
2. Changed the controller code to the following:

```
List<Place> listPlaces;
listPlaces = placeRepository.selectPlaces(idUser);

ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView("/myplaces.html");
modelAndView.addObject("listPlacesBind", listPlaces);
```

That is, instead of using a model class in the middle, wanted to try directly creating the list in the controller and binding it to the view.

But then I get the following error:

```
Property or field 'listPlaces' cannot be found on object of type 'java.util.ArrayList' - maybe not public or not valid?
```

Running in debug mode I set listPlaces to the "watch" view.

Noticed that in the first case it creates two levels of "listPlaces", while in the second case it creates just one level.

So seems it is missing that second level.

So, can't this be done without the need for the middle model class?

Maybe there's a way to add that second level without the need for the middle class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did not show all the relevant code but guessed the missing part, change where needed. One option would be to change your controller method like:

```
@GetMapping("/myplaces")
public String whateverIsTheName(Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("listPlaces", placeRepository.selectPlaces(idUser));
    return "myplaces";
}
```

Without creating any intermediate classes you can use `Model` like above and keep those '*two levels*' so that there is an object where there is this attribute `listPlaces`.

Comment: Awesome solution! This worked. Checked answer as accepted. Thank you.

Comment: Btw, this is the missing part for the controller method that I had before: ```@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "/myplaces")
 public ModelAndView initMyPlaces() {
User loggedUser = new User();
  loggedUser = utilities.getLoggedUser();
Long idUser = loggedUser.getIdUser();
  
  ListPlaces listPlaces = new ListPlaces();
  listPlaces.setListPlaces(placeRepository.selectPlaces(idUser));

  ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView("/myplaces.html");
  modelAndView.addObject("listPlacesBind", listPlaces);
  
  return modelAndView;
 }```

Comment: I changed from modelandview to model like you proposed and it worked perfectly. Even could simplify the html also by removing th:object from the following code: ```<form action="/myplaces" method="post" th:object="${listPlacesBind}">```

Answer (score 1):

You have done a mistake. In the first Controller, you are binding the object of ListPlaces to ModelAndView.

```
ListPlaces listPlaces = new ListPlaces();
listPlaces.setListPlaces(placeRepository.selectPlaces(idUser));

ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView("/myplaces.html");
modelAndView.addObject("listPlacesBind", listPlaces);// Here listPlaces is an Object Of ListPlaces model
```

But in the 2nd Changed, listPlaces is a List not an Object Of ListPlaces model, so in your HTML it is expecting a ListPlaces model's object but getting a list, So it's displaying an error.

```
List<Place> listPlaces;
listPlaces = placeRepository.selectPlaces(idUser);

ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView("/myplaces.html");
modelAndView.addObject("listPlacesBind", listPlaces);// Here listPlaces is a list not an object of ListPlaces model
```

So change your HTML code to accept the list, not the Objet.
If any doubt, let me know.

Comment: how do I change the html to accept the list instead of the object?

Comment: ```
<th:block th:each="place, itemStat : *{listPlaces}">                    
<span th:text="*{listPlaces[__${itemStat.index}__].codPlace}" />
```
in above HTML code itemStat : *{listPlaces}" is a field of ListPlaces class but in second change you are not binding any object of ListPlaces class . In second change the "listPlacesBind" is containing a list so run the th:each  on the  "listPlacesBind" 
as shown below
```
<th:block th:each="place, itemStat : ${listPlacesBind}">
```

Comment: If any doubt please tell.

Comment: listPlacesBind was also part of solution 1. I just forgot to add the code where it's used in the view. Sorry about that. Here it is: ```<form action="/myplaces" method="post" th:object="${listPlacesBind}">```. Anyway, I understood what you suggested doing. So I removed th:object="${listPlacesBind} from the form tag, did the change you proposed (which is the same change suggested by @Santiago Wagner) and it worked. So, thanks a lot. I'm also marking an upvote for this one since already checked another answer as accepted. Thank you. Great solution.

Answer (score 1):

The name listPlaces exists no more in the model since you are now naming it listPlacesBind:

```
modelAndView.addObject("listPlacesBind", listPlaces)
```

That said, the list is no longer a field from an object in the model, you must access it like this:

```
<th:block th:each="place, itemStat : ${listPlacesBind}">                    
<span th:text="${listPlacesBind[__${itemStat.index}__].codPlace}" />
```

Comment: Well, listPlacesBind was also part of solution 1. I just forgot to add the code where it's used in the view. It's here: ```<form action="/myplaces" method="post" th:object="${listPlacesBind}">```. Anyway, I understood what you suggested doing. So I removed th:object="${listPlacesBind} from the form tag, implemented your suggestiong and it worked. I could accept this as an answer, but stackoverflow allows to select just one answer and I had selected another one before. So, giving this an upvote. It is a great suggestion. Thank you.